# Flutter - Locally connect multiple phones running the same app

Tags: dart, flutter, lan

Is it possible to locally connect multiple phones running the same app using Flutter? My intention is to make a local network to allow any of the phones to send data to all other phones connected to that local "session".

I haven't used Flutter yet; the purpose of this question is to decide if I can switch the development of this idea to Flutter. I've found many bluetooth plugins but all of them are used to connect to other kinds of devices, not an app to app connection.

What could be a good plugin to accomplish that?

Comment: Sure, no problem to do that.

Comment: And what is a recommended plugin to do that?

Comment: You don't need a plugin. Dart supports network requests as client or server out of the box.